# "Whether X or whether Y" vs. "Whether X or Y"

Tags: conjunctions, repetition, whether-if

In the following example:

> I wonder whether that is just a way to get more accounts or **whether** it is motivated by some other reasons.

Is the second *whether* in bold letters incorrect, optional, or necessary?

Answer (score 6):

It's not incorrect, and it isn't strictly necessary either, so you could say it was optional. But it feels right in this case because of the length of the sentence and I suspect the writer made that conscious choice to include it. It sort of acts as an indicator that the second possibility is being introduced.

It would feel much more redundant in a short sentence like "*I don't know whether it's right or wrong*".

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any rules against using "whether" twice in a sentence, but in this context, you could omit the second "whether":

> I wonder whether that is just a way to get more accounts or it is motivated by some other reasons.

---

Example sentences shown on [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/whether) also have the same structure, such as:

> To this day, it's unclear whether he shot himself or was murdered.

"or" is used in the same way as your sentence; thus, there isn't a second "whether".

Comment: Thanks, what if the subject differs? E.g., "It's unclear whether *Alex* shot himself or *Bob* was murdered."?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt that doesn't seem like an either / or option. Both could be true. I'd probably say "It's unclear if Alex shot himself *and* if Bob was murdered"

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It will still be the same behaviour with different subjects, you still do not need to use a second "whether". But, realistically the sentence you commented does not make real sense.

Comment: Got it, thanks very much!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If you were taking a reading comprehension test, and you had a single-option multiple-choice question "Which event happened in the text? (a) Alex shot himself, (b) Bob was murdered", then the sentence "It's unclear whether Alex shot himself or Bob was murdered" makes sense, because they're established as mutually exclusive alternatives.

Comment: @Astralbee Alex and Bob are known to have been in the same room at the time of the incident, and Alex was known to have a gun, and a neighbour heard a single shot fired and saw an unidentified silhouette fall. It's unclear whether Alex shot himself or Bob was murdered.

Comment: @stef what is Bob wrestled the gun from Alex and committed the murder? That makes four options. What if Johannes was hiding in the cupboard, popped out and surprised Alex? What if Father Christmas came down the chimney and caught all three of them fighting over the gun?

Answer (score 1):

It should never be necessary to use a second 'whether'.

Broadly, a second 'whether' is only chosen for contradistinction; when it emphasizes a difference and even then, not in most cases.

'Whether it's black or white…' is always sufficient.

'Whether it's black or whether it's white…' serves to emphasize the point… and at least equally clearly, it draws attention to the fact that the speaker isn't a sophisticated user of English.